# What is a sensible approach for enabling/disabling features on a database object?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

Say I have a User database table with the regular username, password, email fields. What is a sensible way to add additional boolean fields that enable/disable features for any given user.

e.g.,

```
user_can_view_page_x
user_can_send_emails
user_can_send_pms
etc
```

Adding a bunch of boolean columns to the existing user table seems like the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would think that this is the wrong approach.

I would rather create a

```
User_Features Table
```

with columns something like

```
UserID
FeatureName
```

And check if a given user has the feature in question enabled/entered in the table.

You could even go as far as creating a `Users_Groups` table, where users are also assosiated with groups and features can be inherited/disallowed from group settings.

Comment: That seems efficient, thanks! I was thinking of doing the same thing but worried that maybe the feature name would be misspelled, but then realized that the web app (or db) could allow only certain features, via a drop down.

Answer (score 1):

I would use three tables.

One is your existing user table:

```
USER table
----
user_id (pk)
name
email
...
```

Another is a table containing possible user privileges:

```
PRIVILEGE table
----
privilege_id (pk)
name
```

Lastly is a join table containing an entry for each privilege setting for each user:

```
USER_PRIVILEGE table
----
user_id (pk) (fk)
privilege_id (pk) (fk)
allowed
```

Here is some sample data for two users, one with the send email privilege and the send pms privilege and another with a view page privilege:

USER data

```
USER_ID  NAME   EMAIL
-------  -----  -------------------
1        USER1  user1@somewhere.com
2        USER2  user2@somewhere.com
```

PRIVILEGE data

```
PRIVILEGE_ID  NAME
------------  -----------
1             view_page_x
2             send_email
3             send_pms
```

USER_PRIVILEGE data

```
USER_ID  PRIVILEGE_ID  ALLOWED
-------  ------------  -------
1        1             'N'
1        2             'Y'
1        3             'Y'
2        1             'Y'
2        2             'N'
2        3             'N'
```

Comment: Is the triple join really necessary?

Comment: @Ramin it provides additional data integrity in that users can only be assigned to a well defined collection of privileges.